# Logging variable data with new format string

Tags: python, python-2.7, string-formatting

I use logging facility for python 2.7.3. [Documentation for this Python version say](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html):

> the logging package pre-dates newer formatting options such as str.format() and string.Template. These newer formatting options are supported...

I like 'new' format with curly braces. So i'm trying to do something like:

```
 log = logging.getLogger("some.logger")
 log.debug("format this message {0}", 1)
```

And get error:

> TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

What I miss here?

P.S. I don't want to use

```
log.debug("format this message {0}".format(1))
```

because in this case the message is always being formatted regardless of logger level.

Comment: You can do this: 
`log.debug("format this message%d" % 1)`

Comment: you need to configure the [`Formatter`](http://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#formatters) to use '{' as style

Comment: @ronak Thanks for the advice but no. Please, see "p.s." section why. BTW log.debug("format this message%d", 1) - works fine.

Comment: @mata How to configure it? Is there direct documentation of doing it?

Comment: @mata I've found it. Please make it an answer so I could set it as "right answer. Thank you once more.

Comment: @MajesticRa - either set it programmatically on the logger, or use a configuration file. Look at the examples in the link.

Comment: How long until there is a solution in the stdlib please Q_Q

Answer (score 39, accepted):

**EDIT:** take a look at the [`StyleAdapter` approach in @Dunes' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24683360/4279) unlike this answer; it allows to use alternative formatting styles without the boilerplate while calling logger's methods (debug(), info(), error(), etc).

---

From the docs — [Use of alternative formatting styles](http://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#use-of-alternative-formatting-styles):

> Logging calls (logger.debug(), logger.info() etc.) only take
>   positional parameters for the actual logging message itself, with
>   keyword parameters used only for determining options for how to handle
>   the actual logging call (e.g. the exc_info keyword parameter to
>   indicate that traceback information should be logged, or the extra
>   keyword parameter to indicate additional contextual information to be
>   added to the log). So you cannot directly make logging calls using
>   str.format() or string.Template syntax, because internally the logging
>   package uses %-formatting to merge the format string and the variable
>   arguments. There would no changing this while preserving backward
>   compatibility, since all logging calls which are out there in existing
>   code will be using %-format strings.

And:

> There is, however, a way that you can use {}- and $- formatting to
>   construct your individual log messages. Recall that for a message you
>   can use an arbitrary object as a message format string, and that the
>   logging package will call str() on that object to get the actual
>   format string.

Copy-paste this to `wherever` module:

```
class BraceMessage(object):
    def __init__(self, fmt, *args, **kwargs):
        self.fmt = fmt
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def __str__(self):
        return self.fmt.format(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
```

Then:

```
from wherever import BraceMessage as __

log.debug(__('Message with {0} {name}', 2, name='placeholders'))
```

Note: actual formatting is delayed until it is necessary e.g., if DEBUG messages are not logged then the formatting is not performed at all.

Comment: As of Python 3.6, you can use f-strings like so:
`num = 2; name = 'placeholders'; log.debug(f'Message with {num} {name}')`

Comment: @P1h3r1e3d13 unlike the logging code in the answer, f''-strings perform formatting immediately.

Comment: Right. They work here because they format and return a regular string before calling the log method. That may or may not be relevant to someone, so I think it's worth mentioning as an option.

Comment: @Jacktose I think users should not log using f-strings, it defeats log aggregation services (e.g. sentry). There's a good reason that stdlib logging defers the string templating.

Answer (score 30):

Here is another option that does not have the keyword problems mentioned in Dunes' answer. It can only handle positional (`{0}`) arguments and not keyword (`{foo}`) arguments. It also does not require two calls to format (using the underscore). It does have the ick-factor of subclassing `str`:

```py
class BraceString(str):
    def __mod__(self, other):
        return self.format(*other)
    def __str__(self):
        return self


class StyleAdapter(logging.LoggerAdapter):

    def __init__(self, logger, extra=None):
        super(StyleAdapter, self).__init__(logger, extra)

    def process(self, msg, kwargs):
        if kwargs.pop('style', "%") == "{":  # optional
            msg = BraceString(msg)
        return msg, kwargs
```

You use it like this:

```py
logger = StyleAdapter(logging.getLogger(__name__))
logger.info("knights:{0}", "ni", style="{")
logger.info("knights:{}", "shrubbery", style="{")
```

Of course, you can remove the check noted with `# optional` to force all messages through the adapter to use new-style formatting.

---

*Note for anyone reading this answer years later*: Starting with **Python 3.2**, you can [use the style parameter](https://docs.python.org/3.2/howto/logging-cookbook.html#use-of-alternative-formatting-styles) with `Formatter` objects:

> Logging (as of 3.2) provides improved support for these two additional formatting styles. The 
>   Formatter class been enhanced to take an additional, optional keyword parameter named `style`. This 
>   defaults to `'%'`, but other possible values are `'{'` and `'$'`, which correspond to the other two 
>   formatting styles. Backwards compatibility is maintained by default (as you would expect), but by 
>   explicitly specifying a style parameter, you get the ability to specify format strings which work 
>   with [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) or 
>   [`string.Template`](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/string.html#string.Template).

The docs provide the example
`logging.Formatter('{asctime} {name} {levelname:8s} {message}', style='{')`

Note that in this case you still can't call the `logger` with the new format. I.e., the following still won't work:

```py
logger.info("knights:{say}", say="ni")  # Doesn't work!
logger.info("knights:{0}", "ni")  # Doesn't work either
```

Comment: Your statement about Python 3 is incorrect. The style parameter only applies to the Formatter format string, not the individual log messages. The page you linked to explicitly says: "There would no changing this while preserving backward compatibility".

Comment: Thanks for keeping me honest. The first part is less useful now, but I've rephrased it in terms of the `Formatter`, which is correct now (I think). The `StyleAdapter`  still works,

Comment: @falstro -- thanks for pointing that out. The updated version should now work. Since `BraceString` is a string subclass, it's safe to return itself from `__str__`

Comment: only answer that mentions style="{", +1

Answer (score 28):

This was my solution to the problem when I found logging only uses printf style formatting. It allows logging calls to remain the same -- no special syntax such as `log.info(__("val is {}", "x"))`. The change required to code is to wrap the logger in a `StyleAdapter`.

```
from inspect import getargspec

class BraceMessage(object):
    def __init__(self, fmt, args, kwargs):
        self.fmt = fmt
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.fmt).format(*self.args, **self.kwargs)

class StyleAdapter(logging.LoggerAdapter):
    def __init__(self, logger):
        self.logger = logger

    def log(self, level, msg, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.isEnabledFor(level):
            msg, log_kwargs = self.process(msg, kwargs)
            self.logger._log(level, BraceMessage(msg, args, kwargs), (), 
                    **log_kwargs)

    def process(self, msg, kwargs):
        return msg, {key: kwargs[key] 
                for key in getargspec(self.logger._log).args[1:] if key in kwargs}
```

Usage is:

```
log = StyleAdapter(logging.getLogger(__name__))
log.info("a log message using {type} substitution", type="brace")
```

It's worth noting that this implementation has problems if key words used for brace substitution include `level`, `msg`, `args`, `exc_info`, `extra` or `stack_info`. These are argument names used by the `log` method of `Logger`. If you need to one of these names then modify `process` to exclude these names or just remove `log_kwargs` from the `_log` call. On a further note, this implementation also silently ignores misspelled keywords meant for the Logger (eg. `ectra`).

Comment: This way is recommend by python doc, https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#use-of-alternative-formatting-styles

Comment: I didn't want to mass-edit/update your answer but I updated it for Python +3.6 /2023 https://stackoverflow.com/a/76582731/9908

Answer (score 23):

The easier solution would be to use the [excellent `logbook` module](http://packages.python.org/Logbook/)

```
import logbook
import sys

logbook.StreamHandler(sys.stdout).push_application()
logbook.debug('Format this message {k}', k=1)
```

Or the more complete:

```
>>> import logbook
>>> import sys
>>> logbook.StreamHandler(sys.stdout).push_application()
>>> log = logbook.Logger('MyLog')
>>> log.debug('Format this message {k}', k=1)
[2017-05-06 21:46:52.578329] DEBUG: MyLog: Format this message 1
```

Comment: This looks great, but is there a way of having milliseconds rather than just seconds?

Comment: @Jeff sure, logbook lets you define custom handlers with and use custom string formats.

Comment: @Jeff Couple of years later - default time precision is milliseconds.

Answer (score 11):

There is now a package on PyPI called [bracelogger](https://pypi.org/project/bracelogger/) that implements the requested functionality.

A demo from the project's [README](https://github.com/pR0Ps/bracelogger):

```py
# import the library
from bracelogger import get_logger

# set up the logger
__log__ = get_logger(__name__)

# use brace-style formatting in log messages
try:
    process(some_obj)
except Exception:
    __log__.warning(
        "Failed to process object '{0!r}' with name '{0.name}' and path '{0.path}'",
        some_obj,
        exc_info=True
    )
```

---

Notes:

- Supports a wide range of Python versions (v2.7 - v3.11)
- No dependencies
- No special syntax (just change the `logging.getLogger` calls and message templates)
- Only enables brace-style formatting for loggers created by the library. This allows for gradually transitioning to brace-style formatting without breaking existing loggers or third party packages.
- The formatting of the message is delayed until it is output (or not at all if the log message is filtered).
- The args passed into the log call are stored on the `logging.LogRecord` objects as usual.

Answer (score 2):

Try `logging.setLogRecordFactory` in Python 3.2+:

```
import collections
import logging


class _LogRecord(logging.LogRecord):

    def getMessage(self):
        msg = str(self.msg)
        if self.args:
            if isinstance(self.args, collections.Mapping):
                msg = msg.format(**self.args)
            else:
                msg = msg.format(*self.args)
        return msg


logging.setLogRecordFactory(_LogRecord)
```

Comment: It does work but the problem is you break third party modules that are using `%` formatting as the record factory is global to the logging module.

Answer (score 2):

This is an update to @Dunes answer as getargspec has been deprecated as of, I believe, Python 3.6.  In addition this also uses the new `stacklevel` argument to fix stack tracing.

```py
#log_helper.py
from inspect import getfullargspec
import logging
import typing as T


class BraceMessage(object):

    def __init__(self, fmt, args, kwargs):
        self.fmt = fmt
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.fmt).format(*self.args, **self.kwargs)

class StyleAdapter(logging.LoggerAdapter):

    def __init__(self, logger:logging.Logger):
        self.logger = logger

    def log(
        self,
        level: int,
        msg: object,
        *args, **kwargs,
    ) -> None:
        if self.isEnabledFor(level):
            msg, log_kwargs = self.process(msg, kwargs)
            # Note the `stacklevel` keyword argument so that funcName and lineno are rendered correctly.
            self.logger._log(level, BraceMessage(msg, args, kwargs), (), stacklevel=2, **log_kwargs)

    def process(self, msg: T.Any, kwargs: T.MutableMapping[str, T.Any]) -> tuple[T.Any, T.MutableMapping[str, T.Any]]:
        # .args[1:] skips over the `self` argument in `logger._log`
        mapped = {key: kwargs[key] for key in getfullargspec(self.logger._log).args[1:] if key in kwargs}
        return msg, mapped

    def addHandler(self, handler):
        self.logger.addHandler(handler)


def getLogger(namespace):
    return StyleAdapter(logging.getLogger(namespace))
```

You would use this like so

```py
from log_helper import getLogger

log = getLogger(__name__)

log.info("Hello {}", "world")
```

Without the `stacklevel` arg, the "funcName" and "lineno" values would always be `StyleAdapter`'s `log` method.

Answer (score 1):

I created a custom Formatter, called [ColorFormatter](https://pypi.org/project/out/) that handles the problem like this:

```
class ColorFormatter(logging.Formatter):

    def format(self, record):
        # previous stuff, copy from logging.py…

        try:  # Allow {} style
            message = record.getMessage()  # printf
        except TypeError:
            message = record.msg.format(*record.args)

        # later stuff…
```

This keeps it compatible with various libraries.
The drawback is that it is probably not performant due to potentially attempting format of the string twice.

Answer (score 1):

I see it's an old question and there are good answers, but I see no mentions of basicConfig so here's a quick summary:

Starting from Python 3.2 you can use the `style` parameter in basicConfig:

```
logging.basicConfig(format='{levelname}:{name}:{message}', style='{')
```

or in Formatter:

```
...
handler = logging.StreamHandler()
handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('{levelname}:{name}:{message}', style='{'))
...
```

`'{levelname}:{name}:{message}'` is the default, you can replace it with whatever you want.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig
https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#use-of-alternative-formatting-styles

Answer (score 0):

Similar solution to pR0Ps' , wrapping [`getMessage`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L360) in `LogRecord` by wrapping [`makeRecord`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L1538) (instead of `handle` in their answer) in instances of `Logger` that should be new-formatting-enabled:

```py
def getLogger(name):
    log = logging.getLogger(name)
    def Logger_makeRecordWrapper(name, level, fn, lno, msg, args, exc_info, func=None, extra=None, sinfo=None):
        self = log
        record = logging.Logger.makeRecord(self, name, level, fn, lno, msg, args, exc_info, func, sinfo)
        def LogRecord_getMessageNewStyleFormatting():
            self = record
            msg = str(self.msg)
            if self.args:
                msg = msg.format(*self.args)
            return msg
        record.getMessage = LogRecord_getMessageNewStyleFormatting
        return record
    log.makeRecord = Logger_makeRecordWrapper
    return log
```

I tested this with Python 3.5.3.

Comment: This determines where the load of actually interpolating the string goes. Do you front-load it at record creation time, ensuring a static string is what escapes the back-end, or do you only perform formatting if the message is ultimately displayed.  Simple case: the message is actually below the acceptable level for display.

Additionally: this is not a good way to "patch" things.  Actually construct a Logger subclass and use that, man.

Answer (score 0):

Combined `string.Formatter` to add `pprint.pformat` type conversion and from `logging`: `setLogRecordFactory`, `setLoggerClass`. There's one neat trick- i create extra nested tuple for argument `args` for `Logger._log` method and then unpack it in `LogRecord` init to omit overriding in `Logger.makeRecord`. Using `log.f wraps` every attribute (log methods on purpose) with `use_format` so you don't have to write it explicitly. This solution is backward compatible.

```
from collections import namedtuple
from collections.abc import Mapping                                                     
from functools import partial                                                          
from pprint import pformat                                                              
from string import Formatter                                                        
import logging                
                                                       
                                                                                        
Logger = logging.getLoggerClass()                                                       
LogRecord = logging.getLogRecordFactory()                                               
                                                                                      
                                                                                        
class CustomFormatter(Formatter):                                                       
    def format_field(self, value, format_spec):                                         
        if format_spec.endswith('p'):                                                   
            value = pformat(value)                                                      
            format_spec = format_spec[:-1]                                              
        return super().format_field(value, format_spec)                                 
                                                                                        
                                                                                        
custom_formatter = CustomFormatter()                                                    
                                                                                        
                                                                                        
class LogWithFormat:                                                                    
    def __init__(self, obj):                                                            
        self.obj = obj                                                                  
                                                                                        
    def __getattr__(self, name):                                                        
        return partial(getattr(self.obj, name), use_format=True)    

                
ArgsSmuggler = namedtuple('ArgsSmuggler', ('args', 'smuggled'))                                                                                     
                                                                                        

class CustomLogger(Logger):                                                             
    def __init__(self, *ar, **kw):                                                      
        super().__init__(*ar, **kw)                                                     
        self.f = LogWithFormat(self)                                                    
                                                                                        
    def _log(self, level, msg, args, *ar, use_format=False, **kw):                                         
        super()._log(level, msg, ArgsSmuggler(args, use_format), *ar, **kw)                                     
                                                                                        
                                                                                        
class CustomLogRecord(LogRecord):                                                       
    def __init__(self, *ar, **kw):                                                   
        args = ar[5]
        # RootLogger use CustomLogRecord but not CustomLogger
        # then just unpack only ArgsSmuggler instance
        args, use_format = args if isinstance(args, ArgsSmuggler) else (args, False)                                       
        super().__init__(*ar[:5], args, *ar[6:], **kw)                                  
        self.use_format = use_format                                                    
                                                                                        
    def getMessage(self):                                                               
        return self.getMessageWithFormat() if self.use_format else super().getMessage() 
                                                                                        
    def getMessageWithFormat(self):                                                     
        msg = str(self.msg)                                                             
        args = self.args                                                                
        if args:                                                                        
            fmt = custom_formatter.format                                               
            msg = fmt(msg, **args) if isinstance(args, Mapping) else fmt(msg, *args)    
        return msg                                                                      
                                                                                            
                                                                                                
logging.setLogRecordFactory(CustomLogRecord)      
logging.setLoggerClass(CustomLogger)              
                                                  
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)   
log.info('%s %s', dict(a=1, b=2), 5)          
log.f.info('{:p} {:d}', dict(a=1, b=2), 5)
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's something real simple that works:

```
debug_logger: logging.Logger = logging.getLogger("app.debug")

def mydebuglog(msg: str, *args, **kwargs):
    if debug_logger.isEnabledFor(logging.DEBUG):
        debug_logger.debug(msg.format(*args, **kwargs))
```

Then:

```
mydebuglog("hello {} {val}", "Python", val="World")
```