# How to make a logger work with string.format instead of string formatters

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, logging, string-formatting

Right now I have a lot of code that uses the traditional C-style string formatters, i.e.

```
print "Hi, %s" % name
```

We're working on transitioning over to using `string.format()`, i.e.

```
print "Hi, {}".format(name)
```

However we're running into issues with logging.  For example, consider the following example.

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig()
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.error("hi %s", "1")
logger.error("hi {}", "2")
```

I would hope that the logging module would be able to make either of these work, however I get the following output to stderr

```
$ python example.py
ERROR:__main__:hi 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 859, in emit
    msg = self.format(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 732, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 471, in format
    record.message = record.getMessage()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 335, in getMessage
    msg = msg % self.args
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
Logged from file example.py, line 6
ERROR:__main__:hi
```

Now we could just change all of our strings involved with logging back to the C-style strings, but that is pretty ugly and worse, inconsistent.  We could also add some extra lines into our code, for example

```
def run_function(func, arg, err_msg, err_msg_params):
    try:
        func(arg)
    except MyException as e:
        logger.error(err_msg.format(err_msg_params))
        logger.exception(e)
        raise
```

But that doesn't seem as clean.  We could also do the formatting before we call this function, and then just not include the `err_msg_params` but that would mean rewriting the function call (and then changing all of the code that uses this function).

Is there a way to make the logging module accept these?  Or do I just have do all of my formatting myself?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/13131400/3001761

Comment: Oops, missed that one somehow.  Thanks @jonrsharpe