# Python logging using custom timestamps (not current timestamp)

Tags: python, logging

I am using the logging module in the following way:

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format='%(asctime)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s',
                    filename=my_filename,
                    filemode='w')
```

and

```
logging.info("Set up logger")
```

for writing. The output is:

```
2017-11-05 19:10:22,762 root      INFO     Set up logger
```

QUESTION: instead of the current timestamp, I would like to have a past (or future, whatever) timestamp. So whenever I want to write something in the log, I can pass the date as argument with something like:

```
logging.info(msg="Set up logger", date='2010-01-01 19:10:22,762')
```

in order to have

```
2010-01-01 19:10:22,762 root      INFO    Set up logger
```

Any help?

Comment: So you want the timestamp to be not the actual timestamp? What's the point of that? If you just want to put arbitrary things in the message you can *already do that*, it's not clear what the problem is.

Comment: If I put it in the message, I won't have a standard format like %(time)s %(name)s %(levelname)s %(message)s

Comment: You can do that formatting yourself.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: With [`time.stftime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.strftime), like what `logging` itself uses.

Comment: It depends exactly what you want. You can do something completely different with e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/13131690/3001761 if you want to. Read the docs, research your options.

Comment: (You'll have to do the millisecond handling yourself, though; `time.strftime` doesn't handle that part.)

Comment: I dont think `time.strftime` is what he wants since this is the same that `logging`does. I think `datetime.datetime.strftime` is what he wants with some defined timestamp. I may be wrong tho.

Comment: Thanks @user2357112 , can you show me a couple of code lines implementing the feature please?

Answer (score 6):

@m1keil's answer will work for simple cases, but gets cumbersome if you want, for example, to have multiple handlers which format the time in different ways, or if you don't need/want to specify the time every time you make a logging call, etc.  Here is a solution which is slightly more complicated, but is the "more correct way", and integrates better with the logging system's normal timestamp handling:

First, you need to create a log filter (filters have the ability to modify log records that pass through loggers they're attached to):

```
class TimestampFilter (logging.Filter):
    """
    This is a logging filter which will check for a `timestamp` attribute on a
    given LogRecord, and if present it will override the LogRecord creation time
    to be that of the timestamp (specified as a time.time()-style value).
    This allows one to override the date/time output for log entries by specifying
    `timestamp` in the `extra` option to the logging call.
    """

    def filter(self, record):
        if hasattr(record, 'timestamp'):
            record.created = record.timestamp
        return True
```

Then, simply create an instance of the filter and add it to an appropriate logger instance:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
filter = TimestampFilter()
logger.addFilter(filter)
```

Then when you want to override the date/time of a log entry, when making the logging call, supply a timestamp in `extra`:

```
my_timestamp = time.time() + 86400  # Let's pretend it's tomorrow already
logger.warn("I am a warning from the future!", extra={'timestamp': my_timestamp})
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do that simply by:

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format='%(date)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s',
                    filename=my_filename,
                    filemode='w')
```

and logging with:

```
logging.info(msg="Set up logger", extra={'date':'2010-01-01 19:10:22,762'})
```

Do note that since you hardcoded the `date` argument in the format, a log message without one will fail. If you want to make it optional, you'll need to use something like `filters` to modify your log message on the fly.

Comment: I tried what you said but it doesn't work:

TypeError: _log() got an unexpected keyword argument 'date'

Comment: my bad @riccio777, updated the code (forgot it's the extra arg).

Comment: Thank you, just one little thing: date in the dictionary should be with the quotes.

Comment: I will test my code before I post next time :|
glad I could help