# queue consumer print vs logging

Tags: python, multithreading, logging, queue

While debugging a queue example below, I found a weird (to me) behavior related to the print function in Python 3.6. The below code works as expected however, if I change the "logger.info" with "print" function in the consumer function below, the consumer function hangs. Why is that so?

```
from queue import Queue
from threading import Thread
import logging

logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s; %(name)s; %(levelname)s; %(message)s', level=logging.DEBUG)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.info('Starting...')


def consumer(q):
    while True:
        item = q.get()
        logger.info ("Working on item: {}".format(item))


def main():
    q = Queue()

    t = Thread(target=consumer, args=(q,))
    t.start()

    for i in range(3):
        q.put(i)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output 1:

```
2018-02-20 09:24:29,630; __main__; INFO; Starting...
2018-02-20 09:24:29,631; __main__; INFO; Working on item: 0
2018-02-20 09:24:29,631; __main__; INFO; Working on item: 1
2018-02-20 09:24:29,631; __main__; INFO; Working on item: 2
```

Output 2:

```
2018-02-20 09:26:14,497; __main__; INFO; Starting...
```

Comment: Maybe its output buffering. In Python 3.x you have extra argument `flush` for `print` function. It's `False` by default. Maybe setting it to `True` will flush output buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably because of `stdout` buffering.

In Python 3.x you have extra argument `flush` for print function. It's `False` by default. Maybe setting it to `True` will flush output buffer.

However, what I wanted to point out is:

```
logger.info ("Working on item: {}".format(item))
```

You should not `format` string and form a logging message this way.

Proper way of doing it is:

```
logger.info("Working on item: %s", item)
```

or maybe

```
logger.info("Working on item: {item}", item=item)
```

Reason: Its better to delay logging message creation until it is really needed, and if it is needed.

You can find more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13131690/3029287).