# Python 3.7 logging: f-strings vs %

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm running into a performance problem in a project, and I narrowed it down to some of the log lines. It seems that f-strings are calculated even when my logging facility is above the level of the line that is logging.

Consider this example to demonstrate the issue:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger('MyLogger')

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, name: str) -> None:
        self._name = name
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        print('GENERATING STRING')
        return self._name

c = MyClass('foo')
logger.debug(f'Created: {c}')
```

When this example is run, I get "GENERATING STRING" printed to screen, indicating that the `__str__` method is being ran even though my logging level is set to `INFO` and the log line is for `DEBUG`.

From what I can tell today, the solution is to use the following vs an f-string.

```
logger.debug('Created: %s', c)
```

There are three things going through my head right now.

- Most of the examples and docs I read seem to be pretty old.
- This project is Python 3.7+ only (not worried about being backwards compatible).
- I have a lot of lines of code to update.

I'm curious to know what others do in this situation.  Is the `%s` the best (most modern) approach?  Is there a more modern way that I should be logging as demonstrated above?

I have a lot of code to update (fix), and I'm hoping to align with modern best practices.

Comment: IMO, use f-strings, they are more efficient *and* more readable.

Comment: Did you read this? https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#optimization You should use `%s` for the exact reason you described above (If I understood it correctly actually)

Comment: @jpp Even if the f-string is always evaluated and the `%` string only if needed within the logging method? (Note: OP is not evaluating the `%` string immediately but passing the parameters to the logging method)

Comment: IIRC, a main advantage of `%` is that the logger will try its best to log *something*, even if interpolating the arguments into the string should fail somehow. f-strings don't have that property, and the entire logging call may fail. Totally `[citation-needed]` though.

Comment: Here's a better link without the `__` requirement: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13131400/logging-variable-data-with-new-format-string/24683360#24683360

Comment: Thanks for linking the possible duplicate @DanielPryden.  I was not able to find those with my Google-foo. Hopefully this post helps the next person!

Answer (score 46, accepted):

IMO, using `%s` in your strings is NOT the most modern approach. Definitely, most developers will prefer to use f-strings because it is more convenient and easy to read (and write).

But, you interestingly find a specific case where you may not want to use an f-string. If you need to avoid automatic call of `__str__()` method because of optimisation issue, then it is probably a good enough reason to use `%s` instead of f-strings. But, this could also indicate that something may be done in your program to reduce the complexity of `__str__()`. Most of the time it shouldn't take so much time or resources to calculate a string representation for an object...

Comment: Agreed, I would defiantly prefer the f-string syntax.  In this case, the `__str__` method converts an epoch timestamp into a human readable date.  It's a performance issue because it's being called millions of times in debug logging.

Comment: Looking at http://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#optimization: "Formatting of message arguments is deferred until it cannot be avoided.". Using f-string syntax might have an extract cost as it will format the message even if it is not logged. See http://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#optimization for additional informations.

Answer (score 103):

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) says that the logging lib is optimized to use the `%s` formatting style. I can't remember where it is mentionned exactly, but I read it a few months ago.

**Edit** - Found! https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#formatting-styles
**Edit2** - *(thanks to Robin Nemeth)*: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#optimization

Comment: here is the link https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#optimization

Comment: Too bad, I think f-strings are much more readable.